# How to pass the value of a list in Django to a method?

Tags: python, html, django, scripting, jinja2

I am trying to do something like this. I have a navigation bar with `li` items:

```
**index.html**
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" name="mis" href="{% url 'pdfNotes'%}">MIS</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'pdfNotes'%}">MA</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'pdfNotes'%}">UXD</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'pdfNotes'%}">OSS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here when I navigate to the first list '

', i.e for **MIS**, I have to redirect to `pdfNotes.html` with the name as 'mis' so that I can use this as a parameter in `views.py` to filter my data and display only 'MIS' details in pdf notes. It is the same for all other `li` items.

```
**pdfNotes.html**
{% if pdfnote %}


<table>

    <tr>
        <th># </th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DOWNLOAD FILE</th>
    </tr>
    {% with counter=1 %}
    {% for item in pdfnote %} 
    {% with crs=item.course %}
    
    <tr>
        <td id="id">{{crs}}</td>
        <td id="id">{{pattn}}</td>
        <td id="id">{{sem}}</td>
        <td id="id">{{ forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td id="name">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td id="downloadBtn">
            <a href="{{item.file.url}}" class="btn-outline-success" download >DOWNLOAD</a>
        </td>    
    </tr>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
</table>


**model.pdf**

class PDF_Notes(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField("File name",max_length=100)
    subject=models.CharField("Subject",max_length=50)
    course=models.CharField("Course",max_length=50)
    semester=models.CharField("Semister",max_length=50)
    year=models.CharField("Year",max_length=50)
    source=models.CharField("Source",max_length=100)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to="media/PdfNotes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


**view.py**

def pdfNotes(request):

    pdfNotes_file=PDF_Notes.objects.all()
    #sub=request.GET[]
    if(request.GET['mis']):
        pdfNotes_file=PDF_Notes.objects.all().filter(subject="MIS")
    n=len(pdfNotes_file)
    print("hello",pdfNotes_file)
    params={'pdfnote':pdfNotes_file,'total_items':n}
    return render(request,'pdfNotes.html',params)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are constructing all url calls in your index.html with the same href, so that is hard to refine later in request processing. Why don't you simply add a parameter to the url with the required pdf sections and check for that?

For example:

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" name="mis" href="{% url 'pdfNotes'%}/mis">MIS</a></li>
```

change in urls.py to accept this parameter:

```
path('pdfNotes/<str:pdf_section>', views.pdfNotes)
```

and process that parameter in views.py:

```
pdf_section = requests.get['pdf_section']
```

and then do with pdf_section whatever you wish.

I hope that I got your question correctly? Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx Branko :) it works perfectly with your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please accept answer

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating the following function:

```
def get_pdf_notes(request, subject):
    pdfNotes_file=PDF_Notes.objects.all().filter(subject=subject)
    n=len(pdfNotes_file)
    params={'pdfnote':pdfNotes_file,'total_items':n}
    return render(request,'pdfNotes.html',params)
```

Add path in the URL for this get_pdf_notes with name `'get_pdf_notes'` and then amend the url in your HTML as follows to pass the argument to the function:

```
<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" name="mis" href="{% url 'get_pdf_notes MIS'%}">MIS</a></li>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'get_pdf_notes MA'%}">MA</a></li>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'get_pdf_notes UXD'%}">UXD</a></li>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'get_pdf_notes OSS'%}">OSS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanx, Ahmed, I got your idea behind :) I tried this with little changes in url.py and it works.